# How exclude files from the module loader sails.js uses internally

Tags: sails.js

I'm using sails.js with a module i created called [def-inc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/def-inc) to get some sort of inheritance into controllers and models via mixins. Now i want to store the mixins/traits in a traits folder inside models and controllers. I don't want to pollute the api root with another folder to hold my traits, **so the ponint is that if it is possible to exclude a folder or a file, with out having to modify the core files?**, or at least a way to override the module-loader and configure it to do this.

This is an example of the path structure i want to use, but without getting extra models/controllers.

```
.                                         
|-- api                         
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- traits
|   |   |  |-- accountTraits.js
|   |   |-- User.coffee
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- traits
|   |   |  |-- restfullTraits.js
|   |   |-- UserController.js
```

Right now if i do that, i get an extra model called accountTraits (and a table if using mysql adapter).

I've checked the code and documentation, and so far this doesn't seem to be supported atm, but since probably it is a regular pattern (outside sails, rails, laravel, etc) to use other objects that are part of the model domain, but aren't specific db models, i assume that someone have done something similar.

Note: I know that for simplicity i can just move the traits folder to the api root path, and i don't consider traits to be part of services, so please avoid answering that, if it isn't possible, just comment my question.

**EDIT:**
Based on the code provided by **@sgress454**, i created this code, just to support loadModels too (Which works in the same way), and have a single fn to modify in case i want to apply the same behavior to other moduleLoader methods. Anyways, i'll leave it here just in case somebody needs it (But **be sure to upvote @sgress454** :)

```
var liftOptions = rc('sails');
  // Create the module loader override function
  liftOptions.moduleLoaderOverride = function(sails, base) {
    // Get a reference to the base loaders methods we want to extend
    var baseLoadController = base.loadControllers;
    var baseLoadModels = base.loadModels;

    // Reusable fn to remove modules that match the defined pattern
    var removeTraitsFromAutoLoadModules = function(cb, err, modules){
      // Remove all modules whose identity ends with "traits"
      modules = _.omit(modules, function(module, identity) {
        return identity.match(/traits$/);
      });
      // Return the rest
      return cb(err, modules);
    };

    return {
      loadControllers: function (cb) {
        baseLoadController(removeTraitsFromAutoLoadModules.bind(null, cb));
      },
      loadModels: function(cb) {
        baseLoadModels(removeTraitsFromAutoLoadModules.bind(null, cb));
      }
    };
  };


  // Start server
  sails.lift(liftOptions);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the module loader by passing a `moduleLoaderOverride` function as an option to `sails.lift`.  The function takes two arguments--a reference to the Sails instance, and an object containing the original module loader methods so that you can still call them.  The function should *return* an object containing methods of the module loader that you'd like to override.  For example:

```js
// bottom of app.js

// Get the lift options from the .sailsrc file
var liftOptions = rc('sails'); 

// Include lodash (you may have to npm install it), or else rewrite
// below without the _.omit call
var _ = require('lodash');

// Create the module loader override function
liftOptions.moduleLoaderOverride = function(sails, base) {
  // Get a reference to the base loadControllers method we want to extend
  var baseLoadControllers = base.loadControllers;
  return {
    loadControllers: function (cb) {
      // Load all of the controllers
      baseLoadControllers(function(err, controllers) {
         // Remove all controllers whose identity starts with "traits"
         controllers = _.omit(controllers, function(controller, identity) {return identity.match(/^traits/);});
         // Return the rest
         return cb(err, controllers);
      });
    }
  };
};

// Lift Sails
sails.lift(liftOptions);
```

You'll have to lift your app with `node app.js` for this to work--there's no way to put this in a regular configuration file and use `sails lift`, since those are loaded by the module loader!

Comment: +1 Awesome, it works as expected, you had a little bug in the return statement, since you placed the var definition inside it, instead of before the block, but anyways, awesome answer. I tweak it a lil bit just to override the loadModels too, i'll add the code to my question for future reference.